# How to determine if a user is newly created or an existing user in Firebase auth?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Following listener is used to detect if a user is logged in,

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){})
```

is there a way to determine if the user is created with

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword()
```

or due to a login with:

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword()
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

After **createUserWithEmailAndPassword()**

```
user.emailVerified is false
```

After **signInWithEmailAndPassword()** (assuming the user has verfied their email)

```
user.emailVerified is true
```